# C# Entity Framework migration, Make ID auto-increment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, ef-database-first

I have a table that is used in an Entity Framework context that was generated using a database-first approach.

I made a mistake, and the `ID` for one table is not auto-incrementing. I am unsure as to what the best approach to solve this is.

Should I drop the table, and generate it again?

Can I make a migration to make this ID auto-increment?

Is there another option?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This **highly** depends on what **database system** you're talking to through EF. In **SQL Server**, you **cannot** turn an existing column into an `IDENTITY` column once it's been created - you'll have to drop and re-create with the correct settings. But other RDBMS might have other means of solving this ....

Comment: Migrations are for code first. Are you using code first with an existing database or database first (EDMX)? https://romiller.com/2013/04/30/ef6-switching-identity-onoff-with-a-custom-migration-operation/

Answer (score 0):

If the table was created using Database first you can alter it in SSMS if you use this? Then open up the .edmx file in Visual Studio, right click the background somewhere and select update model from database. Go through the options you need (probably just the refresh table), once you have done this you will need to save the .edmx file.

Answer (score -2):

You can enable code first migrations and update your database:

1. Add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute to your ID column
2. Run this command in Package Manager Console to enable migrations:

   ```
   Enable-Migrations
   ```
3. Update database using these commands :

   ```
   Add-Migration
   Update-Database
   ```

   (First run `Add-Migration`, and then run `Update-Database` command)

Comment: That will not change an existing column to identity. Much more complex. Probably easier to just drop and recreate. https://romiller.com/2013/04/30/ef6-switching-identity-onoff-with-a-custom-migration-operation/